# Verify: If $A$ is a finite set and $f$ is a permutation of $A$ then $f^n = f$ for $n>1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

First we define

> **Definitions**
>
> Let $n$ be an integer $n \ge 0$
>
> Let $f^n$ be $f$ composed with itself $n$ times.
>
> $f^0 = \text{id}_A$ and $f^1 = f$
>
> $f$ is *cyclic* under composition if $f^n = f$ and $n>1$
>
> $f \in \text{Perm}(A) \iff f: A \to A$

Now we state a proposition

> **Proposition**
>
> Let $A$ be a finite set and let $\text{Perm}(A)$ be the set of all permutations of $A$. **All $f \in \text{Perm}(A)$ are cyclic**

Now we state as a lemma

> **Lemma**
>
> Let $\mathcal{P}_n[f] = \{f^j: 0 \le j \le n \}$. If $f^n$ is not cyclic then $f^{n+1} \not \in\mathcal{P}_n[f]$.
>
> Let $n=0$ and because $f$ is not cyclic then $f^{1} \ne \text{ id}_A$. For the induction step, assume $f^n \not \in \mathcal{P}_{n-1}[f]$. Then by $f$ not being cyclic,$f^{n+1} \not \in \mathcal{P}_{n-1}[f] \cup\{f^n\} = \mathcal{P}_n[f]$. This completes the lemma

Finally we can get along with the proof:

> **Proposition**
>
> For (a), let $h^{n+m}:A\to A = h^n: A\to A$ for some $m>n$. Substitute $f=h^n$ and $f^m=h^{n+m}$ If $m < n$ we simply reverse the equality. If $f$ is cyclic then $f = f^m$ for some $m$. **note**: any $\text{Perm}(A)$ is closed under compositions.
>
> Assume for a finite $A$ that $f \in \text{ Perm}(A)$ was not cyclic. The previous lemma provides a $k> |A| + 1$ for which $f^k \not\in \mathcal{P}_{k-1}$. But $|\mathcal{P}_{k-1}| = k-1 > |A|$ and therefore for some $f^\star \in \mathcal{P}_{k-1}$ , $f^\star \not \in \text{Perm} (A)$. But if $f^\star$ is a composition of permutations of $A$ then it is a permutation of $A$. We have just reached a contradiction. We therefore conclude that any permutation of a finite set $A$ is cyclic.
>
> **Corollary**
>
> Let $f \in \text{Perm}(A)$. Then $f$ is cyclic iff $f^{n-1} = \text{id}_A$ for some $n$
>
> If $f$ is cyclic then there exists an $n$ such that $f^n = f$ and therefore $f^{n-1} = f\circ f^{-1} = \text{ id}_A$. Conversely, if $f^{n-1}= \text{id}_A$ then $f^{n-1}\circ f = f^n = \text{id}_A\circ f = f$. Thus $f^n=f$ for a non trivial $n$ and therefore $f$ is cyclic. The corollary is completed.

My concerns are

(1) This is the first time I've written a non-trivial proof, that is, involving two parts. I might have tripped up somewhere

(2) Some term or statement is ambiguous, unnecessary, or not backed up.

**Can you verify the proof and try to address these issues**

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: That someone verify the proof

Comment: It's not really clear what $f$ and $n$ are throughout the post. Do the lemma and the proposition hold for any $f$ and any $n$ ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question. $n$ is an integer $n\ge 0$ and $f \in \text{Perm}(A)$

Comment: For your corollaries you seem to be suggesting that the same $n$ will work for all $f$. That happens to be true, but it's not obvious (and in that case $n$ will not be as small as possible). There's also a much easier way to do this from basic principles. What is the context of this problem? This is something that follows trivially from basic group theory, so I'm guessing group theory is not something you're familiar with or aware of. Computer science?

Comment: I'm from Physics. It was question in an abstract algebra textbook, asked before group theory is introduced.

Comment: (1) Is my first proof correct? (2) Now that I've edited the corollary so that it doesn't say the same $n$ works for all $f$, is what the corollary states obvious?

Comment: What is the basic principles proof?

Comment: I haven't reviewed your work. But you can observe that Perm($A$) is finite so $\{f^n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is finite, so there exist $m,n\in \mathbb N$ with $f^m=f^{n+m}.$ Since $f,$ and any integer power of $f,$ is a bijection we have $f^m=f^{n+m}\implies 1=f^{-m}f^m=f^{-m}f^{n+m}=f^n.$

Comment: @theideasmith I saw your post on Academia SE and then trace you to this post. I'd like to say something here. If this question could bother you, then I think you should go back to school and receive formal education. I was able to solve this problem when I was 13 yr old. I always regret that I did not get PhD. Please do not follow my steps.

Comment: Please don't stalk me. I don't need to justify myself but I will. (1) I'm in Columbia College now. (2) I've been in programming until I recently decided to get into math. (3) I want to make sure I am getting things correct as I am self studying abstract algebra. (4) If you want to insult me then I'll return the favor. I'm sorry but this question of yours isn't very deep (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113132/name-for-cayley-graph-of-a-semigroups)